# Create a List to sort through

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I couldn't find anything on this subject that translated to my current issue so I was hoping I could get some ideas on how to solve the following:

I basically have two lists that each hold the following information with a lot of values:

**List 1:**

```
int row
string text
```

**List 2:**

```
int column
string text
```

What I want to do is consolidate the two lists into one - I don't really know what object to use, though. The closest I know of is a .CSV which has the header information "row","column" and "text". But I don't really want to write a .CSV and then have to load it back into program to work with it further - I want an object/array. Does something like this exist?

After that I also need it to be able to sort the values, so as to sort it by "row" first, then by "column". So that the final product can look like this:

```
row        column        text
0          0             test1
0          1             test2
1          0             test3
...
```

Your help is greatly appreciated (Yes I'm a beginner in C#).

Comment: You should make your own class to store the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<MyClass> list1 = new List<MyClass>();
List<MyClass> list2  = new List<MyClass>();
```

Please note that this MyClass is the class where you are storing your data.

```
// Merge two List
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

and then for Sorting, you can do something like

```
List<MyClass> sortedList = list1.OrderBy(x => x.row).ThenBy(x => x.column).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe what you need is a data structure, a sorted one.
Perhaps a CircularSortedLinkedList should work (research it online). This works if you are going to manage a lot of data. If not, I think you can just compare the strings  with a compareTo (this gets a value which indicates if string1 > string 2 or viceversa and with various if else you can sort it out.

Hope this helps